# Javascript: Callback function called from inside object method producing unexpected results

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have a simple object called RouteLeg that contains a set of Lat/Lng values and has the ability to render a driving route between the two lat/lng points using the google maps api.

In the renderRoad method I call the google maps api DirectionsService.route method, using closure on the callback function so that it has access to the RouteLeg object (self is an object member defined as self = this):

```js
  

directionsService.route(request, (function(obj) {
    return function(result, status) {
        if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
            obj.getDisplay().setDirections(result);
        }
    };
})(self));
```

The code only works if the **display** member variable of RouteLeg (a DirectionsRenderer object) is declared as private (var display) instead of public (this.display).  When display is declared as public it always has a value of null in the callback function.

I'm relatively new to JS and do not understand this behavior.  What am I missing?

(P.S. When I change the scope of the display variable I also change the this.getDisplay function to match.  directionsService and map are global variables).

```js
function RouteLeg(aStart, aEnd) {
  var start = aStart; //an object that contains lat/lng values
  var end = aEnd; //lat/lng object
  this.display = null;  //does not work, only works as when declared as a var 
  var self = this;

  this.getDisplay = function() {
    return this.display;
  }

  this.render = function() {
    renderRoad();
  }

  var renderRoad = function() {
    if (this.display == null) {
      this.display = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer({
        suppressMarkers: true
      });
    }
    this.display.setMap(map);

    var request = {
      origin: new google.maps.LatLng(start.getLat(), start.getLng()),
      destination: new google.maps.LatLng(end.getLat(), end.getLng()),
      travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING
    };

    //directionsService is a global variable for now
    directionsService.route(request, (function(obj) {
      return function(result, status) {
        if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
          obj.getDisplay().setDirections(result);
        }

      };
    })(self));

  }
}
```

Comment: display is an object, where you later refer to a function like this: this.display.setMap(map); So change top declaration to this.display = {};

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is happening because renderRoad does not have an execution context of RouteLeg. Meaning when you are executing `renderRoad`, `this` refers to the global object and not an instance of RouteLeg.

In order to make it work either define renderRoad on the RouteLeg instance:

```
this.render = function() {
  this.renderRoad();
}

this.renderRoad = function() {
```

Or use [call](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call)/[bind](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind)/[apply](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply) to set the execution context of renderRoad to the RouteLeg instance

```
this.render = function() {
  renderRoad.call(this);
}

var renderRoad = function() {
```

Comment: Makes sense.  Thanks for the thorough explanation.

Answer (score 0):

the renderRoad function is being called without the context, ergo the code that sets this.display is setting it on another object then the one passed by self.

```
renderRoad.apply(this)
```

Comment: No need for apply, just use call.